# How do I debug stdin in vscode using python in linux?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, stdin

I am using VS Code on Ubuntu and I wrote this simple python script to read user input from the terminal, just to learn about standard input modes. I want to demonstrate the value in sys.stdin when the standard input mode is set to 'cbreak' (using `tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())`).

I added sys.stdin.read(), sys.stdin.readline() and sys.stdin.readlines() to the watch variables but I am not getting anything. The variables show 'not available' and the local variables on the top left show loading.

How can I watch standard input?

Here is the script and a screenshot below.

```
import sys,tty,termios

old_attr=termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
input()
print("Exit")
termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin,termios.TCSADRAIN,old_attr)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You add a breakpoint in line7.

You coulde press F5 to continue so that you can get the output in the terminal.